# Seasonic 480W PSU not reacting

Tags: power-supply

My Seasonic 480W fanless PSU is connected to a working 230V~ plug and its switch is turned on. Without any changes to the connections inside the PC I can no longer turn it on using the case's switch.

This sounds like the PSU failed, but: I had a very similar issue a year ago and at that time I didn't use the PC for some weeks because I was too lazy to bring it to a repair shop. When I finally did, I wanted to make sure that not some miracle happened which would make me run to the shop without necesity. The PC turned on and ran fine for a year with a few restarts!

What could have caused the PSU to deny service at the time? Could this be the case right now? When can I expect it to be available again? What can I do to accelerate the downtime?

The PSU is built into a BeQuiet Silent Base 800 case with a ASRock X99 Extreme 3 mainboard (manual at http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/x99%20extreme3/#Manual).

Comment: Did you check if the case switch works. (unplug it, use a simple Ohm meter to test. Replug. Should not just have broken but before condemning the PSU do test the switch or press the power button on the motherboard.

Comment: I noticed that the ethernet interface is active (orange LED probably indicating wake-on-lan readyness). Is that a sufficient indicator for the switch being broken (I would get it exchanged in a shop anyway)? The test is tricky because I don't have useful connectors for the ohm meter. Does my mainboard (manual link added above) have a power switch?

Comment: I do indeed not see a dedicated button for that on this motherboard. (Which surprises me. The last few years every motherboard which I bought had one). But the powerbuttons signal to the PSU is done via the 24 pins connector. Briefly shorting the right two should turn the power on.   Note that many PSUs have separate power rails. No idea if this seasonic has those. But inthat case one rail might have failed while the other works. And that would result in 'interesting' behaviour.

Comment: Things I would do at this stage: 1. Reseat and replug connectors. Vabrations can make trhings come loose.  2) If you have a matching other PSU thentest with that.  3) Emulate the switch at the switch connector on the motherboard.  4) Tell the PSU to power up via the 44 pins connector. 5) Give up and buy new stuff or have it tested at a shop with all their equipment.

Comment: The one thing I would jump to first is isolating the PS by unplugging it from everything in the computer and manually shorting the Power ON pins with it isolated; @Hennes #4 I think.